# Datepicker not set date in arabic culture

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have multilingual website. 
But When I change My culture to Arabic, Then After form Submit It does not send date. 
This is my model class

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company foundation date is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime CompanyFoundationDate { get; set; }
```

And My view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyFoundationDate, new { @class = "form-input", id = "foundationDate" })
```

And Inside Jquery I have written This

```
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en']);
        $("#foundationDate").datepicker(
       {
           dateFormat: 'd M yy',
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true
       });
        $("#foundationDate").datepicker('setDate', '@(Model.CompanyFoundationDate.ToDatePickerFormate())');
        $("#foundationDate").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date());
```

It is working fine When I change culture to English but not in Arabic.

In Arabic I have selected date is 12 Feb 2009, But at my action Got `{0001-01-01T00:00:00}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA");
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cultureInfo.OptionalCalendars[5];

var dateTimeString = new String(new[] {
  '1',
  '4',
  '-',
  'ي',
  'و',
  'ل',
  'ي',
  'و',
  '-',
  '2',
  '0',
  '1',
  '5',
  ' ',
  '0',
  '4',
  ':',
  '4',
  '4',
  ':',
  '5',
  '1',
  ' ',
  'م'
});
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString, cultureInfo);


The resulting DateTime is:

2015-07-14T16:44:51

If you want to use DateTime.ParseExact the format is d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt:

var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", cultureInfo);

You should also consider using DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact for better flow of code if you encounter an invalid formatted string.
```

Comment: How I can use it with Model class. and view.

Answer (score 0):

> But When I change My culture to Arabic, Then After form Submit It does not send date

because You trying to send form with 'en' regional settings input.

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en']);
```